# Got UnicodeDecodeError when installing SQLAlchemy via pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install SQLAlchemy via pip. However, I failed.

My OS is Windows 10 Chinese version and I'm using Python 3.6.0.

I searched my problem on the Internet and got many solutions said that I can add sys.setdefaultencoding to some file. But I'm using Python3.

I also found an [issue on Github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4110) which seems to be exactly my problem. But changing my code page to 866 or 65001 doesn't work at all ...

Here's the information:

```
C:\Users\59740>pip install SQLAlchemy
Collecting SQLAlchemy
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.1.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: SQLAlchemy
  Running setup.py install for SQLAlchemy ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 34: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 34: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 1):

open  \python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py   75
return s.decode('**utf_8**') change to

> return s.decode('**cp936**')

other:
chcp cmd show you current code page

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue changing 75 line in "\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py" (thanks to previous comment) to 
`return s.decode('latin1')`.